# x86 mov instruction in C pointer of different size

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to replicate an x86 mov instruction, such as mov %ecx,-0x4(%ebp) in C and am confused about how to do it.  I have an int array for the registers and an int displacement.  How would I move the value of %ecx into the memory address 4 less than the value stored in %ebp?

I have:

```
int* destAddress=(int*)(displacement + registers[destination]);
*destAddress=registers[source];
```

I'm getting a Warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size.

Comment: How do you know that `destAddress` is a valid address? Assuming `displacement` is `-4` and `registers[destination]` is some address. How do you know that this resulting address is even allocated and not pointing to something random?

Comment: To answer your question, you are casting `int` to `int*` which seems to be a problem (is ofcourse undefined behavior). You should consider `size_t` type for `displacement` and `unsigned long long` for `registers` if you are on X86_64.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code example or what you're trying to do...? Where should the result be stored? What is the initial value? are you trying to do: `registers[destination] = registers[source] + displacement`? What's the use of the pointer? what is it supposed to point at?

Answer (score 1):

```
mov %ecx,-0x4(%ebp)
```

or, in Intel syntax:

```
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], ecx
```

is storing the value in `ECX` into the memory location `[ebp-4]`.

`EBP` is the "base pointer" and is commonly used (in unoptimized code) to access data on the stack. Based on the negative offset, this instruction is almost certainly storing the value of `ECX` into the first DWORD-sized local variable.

If you wanted to translate this to C, it would be:

```
int local = value;
```

assuming that `value` is mapped to the `ECX` register, and `local` is a local variable allocated on the stack. Really, that's it.

<sup>[Except that a C compiler would generally put a local variable like this in a register, so this would really translate to something more like `mov edx, ecx`. The only time it would spill to stack would be if it ran out of registers (which isn't uncommon in the very register-poor x86 ISA).

Alternatively, you could force it to spill by making the variable `volatile`: `volatile int local = value;`.
But there is no good reason for doing that in real code.]</sup>

There is pointer dereferencing going on here under the hood, of course, as you see in the assembly-language instruction, but it doesn't manifest in the C representation.

If you wanted to get some pointer notation in there, say you had an *array* of values allocated on the stack, and wanted to initialize its first member:

```
int array[4];
array[0] = value;   // set first element of array to 'value' (== ECX)
```

The displacement (`-4`) won't appear at all in the C code. The C compiler handles that.